# Failed to find style 'null' in current theme in aicharts while drawing barcharts

Tags: android, bar-chart

in my app i want to draw the bar charts.When i define the chartview in xml layout it gives me some warning like "Failed to find style 'null' in current theme" and graphical view of that xml shows a message like "License file is invalid or missing.Please place proper license.lic in assets folder."

**test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
  <com.artfulbits.aiCharts.ChartView
    android:id="@+id/chartView"
    chart="@xml/chart"
    android:background="@android:drawable/alert_dark_frame" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**chart.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<chart>
    <area>
        <area.xaxis title="Sales"/>
        <area.yaxis title="Date"  valuetype="Date"/>
    </area>
    <series type="Bar" color="#FFE0400A" showlabel="true" halign="Near"/>
</chart>
```

I found this example [here](http://www.artfulbits.com/articles/samples/aicharts/sample-viewer.aspx?sample=barsample#Image).

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The example given in the url is not complete source code. I have downloaded the example but ChartView class is missing.

Comment: i have created the example from the above URL but my xml is giving the error,so i cant proceed.i think u must download the aichart.jar and include in your build path.

Comment: Not sure what's wrong with your theme, but the aiChart is a commercial package, so you'd have to pay to remove the "License file is invalid" message.

Comment: did you find out the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Check in your project whether the class named `ChartView` exists in the package `com.artfulbits.aiCharts` com.artfulbits.aiCharts.ChartView

Comment: yes the file exists in the package.but what is wrong with my xml.